# Neo4j beginner: match(agent:Agent) not matching

Tags: neo4j

I recently started neo4j with spring-data. So far all has been working well. But now I wanted to create my first simple query. So I added a Graph Repository with a query with

`@Query(value = "MATCH (agent:Person) Where agent.name = 'Agent' RETURN agent;", elementClass = Agent.class).`

This doesnt return any matches, even though the `findAll()` method of the repository returns all entities from the db.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Environment: neo4j 2.0.0M3 and spring-data 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data Neo4j is not yet compatible with Neo4j 2.0. Thus you can't use labels in your queries.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually the problem was that I upgraded an pre 2.0 db, and so I didnt have any labels set. Until your answer I wasnt aware that my query was using labels. I was only following a tutorial which didnt mention this fact.
Ill set the labels and report back if it works with spring-data(I think it should)